# how can I empty specific folder after a period of time by apache in wamp or any simple and fast way?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, image-uploading, temporary-directory

I have a upload form for register picture of user by PHP.I use Wamp Server.I want when user start uploading file and abandone form because of any reason, uploaded files delete after 10 minutes.

how can I empty specific folder after a period of time by apache in wamp or any simple and fast way?

Comment: Have we not been here at least once before?

Comment: Write a PHP CLI script. Run it every 10 minutes from Task Scheduler